# How can i remove multiple markers in google map flutter

Tags: flutter, error-handling, google-maps-markers, fluttermap

I am showing house number using labeled marker in google map.but i want to show the house number when the zoom is more than 19 and remove all markers when zoom is less than 19.

//this is used to show house number when zoom is more than 19.

```
 void setMarkerValue() async {
  List<MapModel> foundAdd = await houseListController.getHouseList(
      center?.latitude ?? double.parse(coordinates[0]['latitude']),
      center?.longitude ?? double.parse(coordinates[0]['longitude']));
  // List<MapModel> foundAdd =
  //     await houseListController.getHouseList(27.675859, 85.351339);

  print("found add");
  print(foundAdd.length);
  print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
  print(markers.length);

  if (foundAdd.isNotEmpty) {
    for (int i = 0; i < foundAdd.length; i++) {
      houseNumbers.add(foundAdd[i].houseNum!);
      markers
          .addLabelMarker(LabelMarker(
        visible: true,
        onTap: () {
          _showAddressDetail(
              foundAdd[i].fullAddressDetail!,
              foundAdd[i].street!,
              foundAdd[i].zone!,
              foundAdd[i].subZone!,
              foundAdd[i].latitude!,
              foundAdd[i].longitude!);
        },
        label:
            "${foundAdd[i].houseNum.toString()} ${foundAdd[i].subZone.toString()}",
        textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: _selectedMapType == MapType.normal ||
                    _selectedMapType == MapType.terrain
                ? Colors.black45
                : Colors.white,
            fontSize: 22.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            inherit: true,
            shadows: [
              Shadow(
                  // bottomLeft
                  offset: const Offset(-1.5, -1.5),
                  color: _selectedMapType == MapType.normal ||
                          _selectedMapType == MapType.terrain
                      ? Colors.transparent
                      : Colors.black87),
              Shadow(
                  // bottomRight
                  offset: const Offset(1.5, -1.5),
                  color: _selectedMapType == MapType.normal ||
                          _selectedMapType == MapType.terrain
                      ? Colors.transparent
                      : Colors.black87),
              Shadow(
                  // topRight
                  offset: const Offset(1.5, 1.5),
                  color: _selectedMapType == MapType.normal ||
                          _selectedMapType == MapType.terrain
                      ? Colors.transparent
                      : Colors.black87),
              Shadow(
                  // topLeft
                  offset: const Offset(-1.5, 1.5),
                  color: _selectedMapType == MapType.normal ||
                          _selectedMapType == MapType.terrain
                      ? Colors.transparent
                      : Colors.black87),
            ]),
        markerId: MarkerId(foundAdd[i].houseNum.toString()),
        position: LatLng(double.parse(foundAdd[i].latitude!),
            double.parse(foundAdd[i].longitude!)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ))
          .then(
        (value) {
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {});
          }
        },
      );
    }
  } else {
    print("no address found within 200 m");
  }
}
```

//this is google map

Here is code :
Widget CustomGoogleMap() {
return GoogleMap(
onMapCreated: (controller) {
setState(() {
mapController = controller;
});
},
initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
target: LatLng(
double.parse(coordinates[0]['latitude']),
double.parse(coordinates[0]['longitude']),
),
zoom: 15,
),
markers: markers,
mapType: _selectedMapType,
compassEnabled: false,
myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
myLocationEnabled: true,
zoomControlsEnabled: false,
minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(5, 19.5),
onCameraMove: (position) {
setState(() {
currentZoom = position.zoom;
center = position.target;
});
},
// trafficEnabled: true,
onCameraIdle: () async {
if (currentZoom >= 19) {
setMarkerValue();
} else {}
setState(() {});
},
);
}